# How to use values of outside variables into a function?

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a code that generates random numbers from a certain range (as shown in the first function below), and then count how many times each number showed up (as supposedly shown in the second function). How can I apply the second function to the list I made in the first function?

My Code:

```
import random

def create_list(n):
    list_size = n
    number_list = []
    for i in range(list_size):
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        number_list.append(number)
    print number_list
    return number_list

my_list = create_list(5)

def count_list(numlist,c):
    random_list = numlist
    for j in random_list:
        times = random_list.count(c)
    print times

count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],1)
count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],2)
count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],3)
count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],4)
count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],5)
count_list(["""numbers from number_list"""],6)
```

Comment: As a side note, I don't know what your `count_list` function is supposed to do, but here's what it _actually_ does: it loops over the list, setting `times` to the number of times `c` appears in the list over and over again. It forgets all but the last of those identical assignments and returns the last one. So, the whole function could be reduced to `return numlist.count(c)`.

Comment: … except that your existing code will raise an exception if `numlist` is empty, while the simpler version would not.

Comment: A sidenote: the `random_list = numlist` in your `count_list()` function is pointless. Just rename the "numlist" parameter to "random_list" and remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I apply the second function to the list I made in the first function?

The same way you apply it to the number `1`: pass it as an an argument.

```
count_list(my_list, 1)
count_list(my_list, 2)
# …
```

Comment: I've noticed that `my_list` has the value of `None`, so when I try what you've suggested, it prints `0`. Can you give me any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: @RivaEre: That can't be right for the code you're showing. `create_list` can't return `None`. And if `my_list` _were_ `None`, your `count_list` function wouldn't return or print `0`, it would raise `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. If you have a new problem with different code, create a new question, and put the actual code that causes the problem in that new question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
my_list = create_list(5)
for i in range(1, 7):
    count_list(my_list, i)
```

Just pass `my_list` as an argument each time.

If you want to generate different lists for each call:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    count_list(create_list(5), i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the variable `my_list` as an argument to your function `count_list()`.

```
count_list(my_list, 1)
```